# Run method in viewmodel after receiving object in AppShell .NET MAUI

Tags: maui

I am sending a Course object from DashboardViewModel as shown below

**DashboardViewModel.cs**

```
        [RelayCommand]
        async void GoToCourse(Course course)
        {
            if (course == null) return;

            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(TopicSelectionPage), true, new Dictionary<string, object> 
            {
                {"courseSelected", course}
            });
        }
```

to TopicSelectionViewModel which is attached below

**TopicSelectionViewModel.cs**

```
[INotifyPropertyChanged]
    [QueryProperty(nameof(CourseSelected), "courseSelected")]
    public partial class TopicSelectionViewModel
    {
        CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = new();
        [ObservableProperty]
        private Course courseSelected;
        public ObservableRangeCollection<Topic> Topics { get; set; } = new();

        [ObservableProperty]
        private bool isBusy;
        [ObservableProperty]
        private string title;
        [ObservableProperty]
        private string imageURL;


        [RelayCommand]
        async Task Refresh()
        {
            Topics.Clear();

            IsBusy = true;

            try
            {
                if (courseSelected is not null)
                {
                    Title= courseSelected.Title;
                    ImageURL = courseSelected.ImageURL;

                    if (courseSelected.CourseRef.Equals("anat1"))
                    {
                        foreach (Topic item in Constants.GetAnatomyTopics)
                        {
                            Topics.Add(item);
                        }
                    }
                    else if (courseSelected.CourseRef.Equals("phys1"))
                    {
                        foreach (Topic item in Constants.GetPhysiologyTopics)
                        {
                            Topics.Add(item);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to run the *RefreshCommand* after receiving the Course object. I tried calling the RefreshCommand in the constructor but the command is called before receiving the Course object. How do I go about this?

Comment: Is there a reason not to use OnAppearing instead? I use ApplyQueryAttributes and OnAppearing to handle this logic.

Comment: OnAppearing is in the code behind, not in the ViewModel.

Comment: All my OnAppearing commands are in my ViewModel. I do not keep code in my Views. EventToCommandBehavior is the way to go.

Comment: I have added some code, so you can see how it is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to add OnAppearing to your ViewModel:

```
<ContentPage.Behaviors>
    <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior
            EventName="Appearing"
            Command="{Binding AppearingCommand}" />
</ContentPage.Behaviors>
```

Where toolkit is:

```
xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
```

How to use code when assigning:

```
public void ApplyQueryAttributes(IDictionary<string, object> query)
```

When, your ViewModel is implementing:

```
IQueryAttributable
```

Edit: Instead of doing this to your ViewModel:

```
[INotifyPropertyChanged]
[QueryProperty(nameof(CourseSelected), "courseSelected")]
```

You can do this:

```
public partial class TopicSelectionViewModel : ObservableObject, IQueryAttributable
```

And then add this method:

```
public void ApplyQueryAttributes(IDictionary<string, object> query)
```

And get your data with:

```
query["SomeKey"]
```

Comment: Please help me. Where is the ```ApplyQueryAttributes``` method going?

Comment: Check the Edit. Is this more clear now?

Comment: I added the event to command behaviour and didn't use the other part and it's working. I am using [QueryProperty] in my view models which I think is the same way to do the same thing

Comment: Glad you got your problem fixed. I want to add something about [QueryProperty]. Annotations are good. But the code they generate, is somewhere in the black box (partial classes, etc... ) Implementing the IQueryAttributable interface, exposes the code to your ViewModel, so you can have control over it.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to create the class you are passing to your second VM as an ObservableProperty in your second VM then using On*NameOfClassBeingPassed*Changed you can then call the command which will occur after the class is instantiated. No need for any xaml or OnAppearing code.

```
[ObservableProperty]
    Course courseSelected;
    partial void OnCourseSelectedChanged(Course value)
    {
        Refresh();
    }
```